# How to disable ufw on boot?

Tags: 20.04, ufw

Azure Virtual Machine, OS: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Every time I restart the VM, ufw status is active. My objective is to prevent this and make ufw inactive on boot.

What I have tried:

```
sudo ufw disable
```

However ufw status will still be active on the next reboot. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 4):

You can indeed stop the service with your command, but obviously it will be restarted next time. What you need to do, instead, is disable the service that starts `ufw` during the boot process of the computer.

```
sudo systemctl disable ufw.service
```

If you want to restore the service, substitute `disable` by `enable` in this command.

If you never want to hear about `ufw` again on that system, you also can completely remove it from your system: that will remove the systemd service and the program.

```
sudo apt purge ufw
```